# does thymeleaf support auto binding form 1:n relation?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-boot

There are two entities User, Group.
Group has many users.

User.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="group_id")
private Group group;

public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Group group) {
    this.group = group;
}
```

Group.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="group")
private List<User> users;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

form.html

```
<form th:object="${user}" class="form-horizontal" role="form"th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.servletPath}}" method="post">
    <label for="group****????" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group: </label>
    <input type="text" name="group****??????" required="required" />
 ...</form>
```

I want to bind group_id automatically.
But I don't know getter, setter about group and group_id
and pass parameters to controller.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help: [Thymeleaf User Guide: Iteration](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#iteration)?

Comment: Yep. That should be it. Its a bit of fiddeling because of the manual iteration index usage but thats the way to go.

Comment: My question shows auto binding for normal fields(user.name, user.email, user.address) but foreign keys(group_id) isn't binded.

Comment: In my experience, there is no "magic" available to auto-bind lists of things.  You have to iterate over them and manually build the fields, as suggested by @DaveSyer